# Question about the notation $C(X)$, $\mathbb{R}^C$, $\mathcal{C}^\star$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation

My question is quite simple and is all about the meening of different symbols.

I have studied math a few years and came accross the notation below relatively often, but I noticed that in many papers, it isn´t even explained. That´s why I think that this is so trivial and agreed upon accross mathematics that it doesn´t even need to be specified.

Please could you affirm that I read that notation correctly?

1. $C(X)$ = the set of all continuous functions with domain $X$
2. $\mathbb{R}^C$ = the set of all functinuous from $C$ to $\mathbb{R}$
3. $\mathcal{C}^\star$ = the set of all differentiable (smooth) functions

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis) help ? 1. and 2. are ok 3. I have personally never seen.

Comment: Usually the set of smooth (infinitely times differentiable) functions on $\mathbb R$ is denoted by $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. There is also a variation $C^k(\mathbb R)$ which is the set of $k$-times differentiable functions. If you come across this  $\mathcal C^*$ in more than one paper by different authors, I doubt it is the set of smooth functions. To me (I might be wrong) it suggests a certain algebra.